# How to use the Queen in the StarCraft 1 single player campaign

Tags: starcraft-zerg, starcraft

I am playing the single player campaign of StarCraft (StarCraft 1) on a Windows PC. I am about midway through the Zerg campaign where the game allows you to morph Queens. I don't understand how to use Queens though. What can I do with a Queen?

I mean, is a Queen an attacking unit? Or a defensive unit? Or a scouting unit? There is one map where the game gives me two Queens at the outset, but I don't use them for anything.

Comment: The _easiest_ way for a beginner to use a Queen is probably [casting Spawn Broodling on Seige Tanks](https://liquipedia.net/starcraft/Spawn_Broodling#Competitive_Usage)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Queens are mainly casters with 4 main skills:

- It has the built in **parasite** spell that enables you to see the same things the host with the parasite can.  (This can be removed only by the medic's restoration)
- It can **Ensnare** a group of units slowing them.  This can be used to either prevent them from escaping or slowing their advance.
- **Spawn Broodlings** can also be researched to turn any ground unit into two broodlings, instantly killing the unit in the process.  I don't know what mission your playing, but if that's the first mission in brood war, then you're supposed to use spawn broodlings on the ultralisks your about to come across, effectively rendering them useless. Alternately you can ensnare them and have your hunter killers have a go at them.
- Last but not least, they can **infest** a terran command center which turns said command center into a terrorist-training academy for suicidal infested terrans.

Comment: Ensnare also [reduces rate of fire](https://liquipedia.net/starcraft/Ensnare#Effects_on_Rate_of_Fire) by about 18% on average

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about the campaign, it's been ages since i played it, but Queens have several good uses:

1. They can insta-kill any ground unit with broodlings, which works especially well against defending siege tanks (sometimes causing a chain reaction destroying more of the tanks through siege tank AoE if more of his tanks are in range and fire on the broodlings), ultralisks or to harass enemy workers by turning them into broodlings which attack the other workers.
2. Ensnare is a good way to prevent enemies from retreating or delay their attacks so you have time to build up more defense. It also works wonders against enemy melee that tries to get close to your ranged units and afair it also shows you cloaked enemy units (if you manage to get ensnare on them).
3. Against CPU it's funny to infest command centers and use suicide bombers to kill anything in their path but usually there is no practical use for that.
4. The parasite is the ultimative scouting ability. Use it on as many enemies as possible (in multiplayer especially on units the other player won't select often so he won't remove it, i.e. workers or overlords) to keep track of any movement he makes. He won't be able to suprise you and afair it can even be used on enemy detectors to allow you to detect his own hidden units. For non-terrans the only way to get rid of parasites is to kill the unit in question which is especially bad on bigger units.

Answer (score 0):

Mainly you want to use the Queen for **Parasite** and **Infest** abilities.

Use **Parasite** like crazy, especially on Terran Transports, and do not shoot them down (yet). It will show you where their base is and notify you of when they are about to attack. Same deal with any other units you can get ahold of, like ground units such as marines or SCV workers, who are likely to stick around the base and not be disposed of shortly.

In one or two missions you have several terran bases, some of them less defended than others. Here is where you want to use the **Infest** ability, shortly after hitting one of the smaller bases. Then you get the poppers. Make sure if you're using poppers that you only send them in one at a time and keep them clear of your assaulting units. You can have them all coming in but space them out significantly in a line then order them all to go (this way they will avoid blowing each other up)

Comment: You're using a bit of slang here, like 'Poppers' for (I'm assuming) Infested Terrans. It might be clearer if you used the official term at least once, with the slang next to it so other people can associate them together :)

Comment: The unfortunate thing about using **Parasite** in the campaign is that a Terran opponent AI will *always* use **Restoration** on the parasited units.

Comment: @Atav32 medics are only present in BroodWar.  In StarCraft, there's no restoration to worry about.

Comment: @Wildcard yeah, I can't tell from the question which campaign level he's talking about. In general, I consider StarCraft = Brood War, since it's very rare to play pre-expansion StarCraft.

Answer (score -3):

They just cast magic. They are nothing like the Queen you see in Starcraft 2. They are used to disable, support, and harass.